# The essence of "of" preposition

Tags: prepositions

I often notice that the preposition "of" followed by a linking verb.

How in this phrase for example:

> The meaning is of obligation or necessity ...

Why just not to say?

> The meaning is obligation or necessity ...

Another example (from gstreamer documentation) with full context would be:

> So, whether playbin will use hardware acceleration or not will depend on the relative ranks of all elements capable OF dealing with that media type.

**capable OF dealing with**

What the preposition *of* means in this sentence? And in the sentence above! I suspect that the meaning is the same. But I just need the strict grammar rule for it. And may be some more examples)

Comment: Do you have the whole paragraph that this example comes from? It would be helpful to have more context.

Comment: Broadly, "The meaning is of obligation or necessity ..." is less and "The meaning is obligation or necessity ..." more specific.